# Where should I add more parameters to create a user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have followed a tutorial to create an application that only has 1 type of user. In my own app, I'm trying to have multiple types of user, and show different pages according to what type of user they are.

I find the teacher in the tutorial isn't very clear and I'm not sure how to differentiate between users. So far, all I need for creating a user is `username` and `password`. Also, [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) was of help but still made me confused.

I want to be able to add more fields but, mainly, **differentiate between users (whether they're a Player, Manager or Assistant) during registration**. I thought of passing a `is_player=true` in the POST method for registration but I'm not sure how to add this field to Django registration and then how to create a Player or Manager or Assistant.

In my models, I DON'T create a User model, but I create e model for Player, Manager and Assistant

```
# no User model.

class Team(models.Model):
    name = ...
    ...

class Player(models.Model):
    name = 
    team = models.ManyToManyField(Team)

class Manager(models.Model):
    name = 
    players_responsible_For = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
```

In the serializers file, I DO create a UserSerializer alongside serializers for other models.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return user

class PlayerSerializer(models.Model):
    class Meta:
       model = Player
       fields = '__all__'
    ...
```

Then, this is in my views.py file which also HAS a UserViewSet

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

So, how exactly can I add more fields to creating a user and subsequently create a model for what that user is?

Answer (score 0):

According to what I have understood, you are aware that django has a model name User and you would like to create various other kind of users with different added parameter, you can do it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Player(User):
    address= models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here, you are simply inheriting User class from django.auth and adding your own parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add fields to your models.that will create no hassle.i have suffer few days from it.